# How can I connect the wire that goes to the grounding rod to the grounding electrode system?

Tags: electrical, grounding, electrical-panel

I'm trying to install an outdoor antenna at my parent's house and was wondering how to connect the wire that goes to the grounding rod to the grounding electrode system through the service panel when there doesn't appear to be a grounding bus bar in the service panel.

Here's the inside:

[image: Service Panel]

Comment: In addition to the information in the other question/answers. I'd note that it looks like several wires on the bar are double-lugged. I don't believe that is allowed. I'd suggest adding another ground bar, adding a jumper from the existing bar to it, and separating the grounds and neutrals, just to make things cleaner.

Comment: I'm planning on mounting a GBK10P grounding bar below the breakers. What size must the wire going to one of the screws on the top left bar to the grounding bar be?

Comment: I'm not an expert on that, but reading other answers, it looks like 4AWG copper should work.

Answer (score 0):

There is no separate ground bar in that panel because it is the main panel. Both grounds and neutrals share the same bar. Just know that if you add a ground bar only grounds can terminate on that bar.

For reference: YES, that is a main panel. It is a split-buss panel. The top twelve spaces are "main" breaker spaces, and technically should only have two-pole breakers. Breaker 9/11 is a "lighting main" and controls the bottom 8 breakers.